# Get also WooCommerce product category thumbnail Id using a SQL query

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm using WordPress with WooCommerce and I have written the following SQL query which gets the product category terms IDs names and slugs:

```
SELECT t.term_id AS id, t.name AS post_title,t.slug AS post_url
FROM   wp_terms t 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE  tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
ORDER  BY name
```

How should I change this SQL query to get also the product category thumbnail Id?

**Note:** I'm only interested in a SQL query, but not anything else like a WP_Query.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see the help center (Question Mark in a circle at the top right) about asking a good question. I'm not really sure what you are asking for or what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get additionally **the thumbnail ID** in your SQL query for WooCommerce product category terms, you can use the following instead:

```
SELECT t.term_id AS id, t.name AS post_title,t.slug AS post_url, tm.meta_value AS thumb_id 
FROM   wp_terms t 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta tm ON t.term_id = tm.term_id
WHERE  tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
AND tm.meta_key = 'thumbnail_id'
ORDER BY t.name
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Simple & elegant

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rely on MySQL query my suggestion is please look into the REST API provided by WooCommerce.

For your need the good candidate is

[Get Category](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#retrieve-a-product-category) API service

Which have the details which you expect like this

```
{
  "id": 9,
  "name": "Clothing",
  "slug": "clothing",
  "parent": 0,
  "description": "",
  "display": "default",
  "image": {
    "id": 730,
    "date_created": "2017-03-23T00:01:07",
    "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:01:07",
    "date_modified": "2017-03-23T00:01:07",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:01:07",
    "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_front.jpg",
    "name": "",
    "alt": ""
  },
  "menu_order": 0,
  "count": 36,
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/9"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For multiple categories

[List all product categories](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-product-categories)

Sample output will be like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Albums",
    "slug": "albums",
    "parent": 11,
    "description": "",
    "display": "default",
    "image": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "count": 4,
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/15"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
        }
      ],
      "up": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/11"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Clothing",
    "slug": "clothing",
    "parent": 0,
    "description": "",
    "display": "default",
    "image": {
      "id": 730,
      "date_created": "2017-03-23T00:01:07",
      "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:01:07",
      "date_modified": "2017-03-23T00:01:07",
      "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-23T03:01:07",
      "src": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/T_2_front.jpg",
      "name": "",
      "alt": ""
    },
    "menu_order": 0,
    "count": 36,
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://example/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/9"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://example/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Hoodies",
    "slug": "hoodies",
    "parent": 9,
    "description": "",
    "display": "default",
    "image": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "count": 6,
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/10"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
        }
      ],
      "up": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/9"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

On `All product categories`  API please check available parameters some of the important parameters are:

1. page
2. per_page
3. search
4. hide_empty

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i need mysql query for my project

Comment: Ok, no problem Rohit.